# URL for svn plugin of netbeans

Tags: svn, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

according to [netbeans documentation](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html#checking) to check out from svn:

> Checking out Files from a Repository
>
> If you want to connect to a remote
>   repository from the IDE, then check
>   out files and immediately begin
>   working with them, do the following:
>
> 1. In NetBeans IDE, choose Versioning > Subversion > Checkout
>      from the main menu. The Checkout
>      wizard opens.

that's all well and good.  However, it doesn't seem to be an option.  I have a nice little subversion window with nice little buttons like refresh, commit, etc, but no checkout button, or, more importantly, a way to enter a URL for a repo.

I've gone and installed [Win32Svn](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/), because from the DOS prompt, no svn in the path.  Now there's svn from the DOS prompt, so it's at least on the path.  After restarting NB, still no option to enter a URL.  PEBKAC not impossible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Team->Subversion->Checkout` (tested under Netbeans 6.9).

Comment: ok, thanks :)    instead of googling, should've just poked around randomly.  Guess it was partly being used to NB not having a "team" menu, never bothered to look.  oops.